# XMLHttpRequest readystate stops at 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm feeling a little remedial here as I used to do AJAX natively, but then I worked on a jQuery site for a few years and my native JS got rusty.

I've reduced what I'm doing to the simplest possible code and it's still not working:

```
var rawfile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawfile.onreadystatechange = function() {   
    console.log(rawfile.readyState);
}
rawfile.open("GET", "index.html", true);
```

The expected output would be

```
1
2
3
4
```

but as far as it gets is

```
1
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code. Does anyone see anything totally dumb that I'm missing?

Comment: what status is it returning? `rawfile.status` should get 200 for `ok`

Comment: The status is 0 because the server never actually returns anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to send it...

```
var rawfile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawfile.onreadystatechange = function() {   
    console.log(rawfile.readyState);
}
rawfile.open("GET", "index.html", true);
rawfile.send();
```

see last line...

Comment: Yes! For some reason I didn't notice that in half an hour of trying to figure out what I was missing. I feel both dumb and grateful. Thanks.